# Using optimize() to find a percentile, given a certain value

Tags: r, function, nonlinear-optimization

I have a project for work I've been assigned that I can absolutely not figure out. Background:

Currently we have a script that tells a company how much it will cost them to raise wage disparities to a certain percentile. This is called pcost(p), where you input a number between 0 and 1 and a budget value (in thousands) is returned, for example (made up numbers):

```
> x = pcost(.2)
```

> print(x)
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1euf.png) 451.002

In this case, if we raised the lowest wages to the 20th percentile then it would cost the company about $450k.

What I've been tasked to do is create something that inverses this, such that we would input a desired budget the company has to spend and the output would be the percentile we could raise the lowest wages to. I've been instructed that this should be done by using an optimizer on the following function:

```
pobj = function(p, budget){
  return((budget - pcost(p)^2)) 
}
```

Where we would insert a budget, and the optimizer would find the value of p.

I created the following command using the optimize package, with the idea that in the example below .2 (or near to it) would be the result

```
xmin = optimize(pobj, interval = c(0,1), budget = 451.002, tol = .00001)
```

However, I always get the following error:

```
Error in optimize(pobj, interval = c(0, 1), budget = 500, tol = 1e-05) : 
  invalid function value in 'optimize'
```

I've read the help file, searched here as well as other sites, and can't seem to get a clear explanation on what is causing this error. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I don't have much experience working with optimizers or nonlinear regression in general so it's extremely difficult to troubleshoot on my own.

Any guidance or expertise would be extremely appreciated.

EDIT: as requested by PeterK, the results of pobj at 0 and 1

```
> pobj(0, 455.002)
[1] 207026.8
> pobj(.2, 455.002)
[1] 0
> pobj(1, 455.002)
[1] 18171830
```

EDIT 2: As @AkselA commented, I have also tried running it after pobj was changed to the following:

```
pobj = function(p, budget){
  (budget - pcost(p))^2
}
```

Still produces the following error:

```
> xmin <- optimize(pobj, c(0, 1), tol=0.01, budget=450)
Error in optimize(pobj, c(0, 1), tol = 0.01, budget = 450) : 
  invalid function value in 'optimize'
```

EDIT 3: per @AkselA, a sequential plot pobj. Although there does appear to be a slight dip between index 0-10 I checked the exact numbers and the output does increase at every percentile.

[image: plot(pobj(seq(0, 1, 0.01), 450), type="l")]

FINAL EDIT: Although none of the answers directly solved my problem, AkselA provided the best direction. The problem in running the optimizer did not lay in the optimizer itself, but from pcost(p). By significantly cutting down the code in this function, the optimizer was able to work correctly and the issue was resolved. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To make this a reproducible question, you need to replace your `pobj` with a function that you can share with the community. Minimally, please show us what you get if you call `pobj(0, budget=budget)` and `pobj(1, budget=budget)`.

Comment: @PeterK I have added what I get at 0 and 1 when calling pobj

Comment: Odd that the plot index only runs to 60, it should be 1/0.01 = 100. Are there missing values? Or more likely `NULL`s?

Comment: Looking at the df output, everything levels out at the 67th percentile -- the values are identical. From my understanding, that is the maximum amount you would need to raise wages to eliminate differences between groups according to the logic of pcost. I've tried constraining pobj by this interval i.e. c(0,.6), but the same error is produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you just misplace the parentheses? Your `pobj()` don't have a minimum.

Assuming a simple `pcost()`:

```
pcost <- function(x) exp(x*2)*100 - 90

pobj <- function(p, budget){
   (budget - pcost(p))^2
}

xmin <- optimize(pobj, c(0, 1), tol=0.01, budget=450)
xmin
# $minimum
# [1] 0.8443315
# 
# $objective
# [1] 1.498106
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your point about the parentheses. As far as I can tell the way you wrote xmin is the same as I did, minus the explicit calls. I also tried using the way you wrote it in R and still got the invalid function value. One thing to note: the pcost function we use is much more involved than what you wrote -- it runs through multiple datasets and cleans/manipulates multiple variables before getting to the end point where it returns a final value based on a calculated dataframe. Does optimize require me to ONLY contain the relevant calculation in pcost?

Comment: @Dr.Fishopolis: In your code you square `pcost(p)`, not the `budget` – `pcost(p)` difference. The `^2` should be moved one parenthesis out.

Comment: my apologies for not clarifying, I also updated pobj based on your change -- still getting "invalid function value in 'optimize'". I'll update the question body as well

Comment: Does your `pcost()` increase monotonically (any local minima)?

Comment: Have you looked at `plot(pobj(seq(0, 1, 0.01), 450), type="l")`?

Comment: From what I was told, pcost should be monotonic, although there does seem to be a slight dip from index 0 - 10 (plot in question body). This is at the limits of my background -- would something like that prevent the optimizer from working? In what way?